# Добавление ключа сообщения kafka к существующим консьюмерам

Tags: apache-kafka

На текущий момент имеется реализация отправки сообщений в kafka без указания ключа (key) сообщения. Уже есть реализованные листенеры у потребителей. Сейчас занимаюсь рефакторингом.

И возник вопрос необходимости внедрения ключа (key) для обеспечения строгого инкремента.
Я не очень глубоко знаком с разновидностями реализаций, только с основными.

Поэтому вопрос: не сломаю ли я какую-либо реализацию листенера при внедрении ключа? Чисто теоретически и по проверкам основных реализаций - всё нормально: просто ключ игнорируется. Но нет ли тут каких-то подводных камней, которых, в силу своих поверхностных знаний, я не учёл?

Comment: Не сломаешь. А что за строгий инкремент? Ключ используется для партиционирования, если кастомной стратегии не указано. Соответственно, из разных партиций сообщения могут прийти не в том порядке, что отправлялись.

Comment: Так и есть. Речь о партицировании. Необходимо, чтобы порядок чтения соответствовал порядку записи по эдакому уникальному идентификатору. Решение было в пользу ключа. Спасибо за ответ о реализациях!

Comment: Ключ тогда не должен быть уникальным. Наоборот, те записи, что должны быть последовательными, должны иметь одинаковый ключ

Comment: Видимо, неправильно выразился. Слово "уникальному" было лишнее